# Snap pea seedlings wilting

Tags: seedlings, pest-damage, peas, wilting

I transplanted some snap pea (sugar bon from Baker creek) seedlings a few weeks ago. For a while they were looking great and starting to grow. Then several of them started to wilt and turn white. When I pulled them out their roots seemed short and stunted.
Any idea on what caused this? I replaced them with new seedlings but I'm worried the issue will continue.

Edit to say: I'm in zone 7 and transplanted before our last frost. We've been getting normal amounts of rainfall so the garden soil has been moist but it drains well so there's no standing water.

[image: seedling]

Comment: Peas don't like transplanting, on average. Stick the seed in the ground as early as you can work the ground right where you want them is the typical approach.